# did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line ... for Arabic lang file of Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode

it is the usual

```
did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line xx column yy
```

error for Rails language YML files. In this file, I have Arabic language.

Here are the facts:
1. This file has worked before.
2. I added some variables and made some new translations.
3. Now I see the error above when I deploy as well as using [YAMLLINT](http://www.yamllint.com/)
The line that causes the error is the **second** line below (column 7):

```
    status:
      payment_errored: "فشل الدفع، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى."
      payment_errored_starter: "الدفع فشلت، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى. إذا استمرت المشكلة، يرجى الاتصال بالدعم Sharetribe".
      payment_errored_starter: "الدفع فشلت، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى. إذا استمرت المشكلة، يرجى الاتصال بالدعم Sharetribe".
      payment_errored_author: "فشل الدفع، الرجاء الاتصال %{starter_name} ونطلب منهم لمحاولة دفع مرة أخرى."
      cancel_payed_transaction: إلغاء
```

(the top line has 4 spaces and the next 5 lines all have 6 spaces at the beginning)

4. After I removed the second line, YAMLLINT recognizes the next line as error! This happens for all of the next lines except the last one (cancel_payed_transaction)
5. I checked the unicode characters of the second line in Excel and it all seems OK:
   a. There are 6 spaces to start
   b. The space is a good one (unicode = 32)
   c. The colon (:) and double quotes are good (unicode = 58 and 34)

Comment: Can you try the second line without full stop and comma  and tell us the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dots at the end of third & fourth lines, try this:

```
status:
  payment_errored: "فشل الدفع، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى."
  payment_errored_starter: "الدفع فشلت، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى. إذا استمرت المشكلة، يرجى الاتصال بالدعم Sharetribe"
  payment_errored_starter: "الدفع فشلت، يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى. إذا استمرت المشكلة، يرجى الاتصال بالدعم Sharetribe"
  payment_errored_author: "فشل الدفع، الرجاء الاتصال %{starter_name} ونطلب منهم لمحاولة دفع مرة أخرى."
  cancel_payed_transaction: إلغاء
```

Comment: Grah I checked everything except that one. Wow thanks a lot!